# How to restrict the area in which LinkExtractor is being applied?

Tags: scrapy

I have a scraper with the following rules:

```
rules = (
  Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\S+list=\S+'))),
  Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\S+list=\S+'))),
  Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\S+view=1\S+')), callback='parse_archive'),
)
```

As you can see, the 2nd and 3rd rules are exactly the same.

What I would like to do is tell scrappy extract the links I am interested in by referring to particular places within a page only. For convenience, I am sending you the corresponding XPaths although I would prefer a solution based on BeatifullSoup's syntax.

```
//*[@id="main_frame"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]

//*[@id="main_frame"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]

//*[@id="main_frame"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]
```

**EDIT:**

Let me give you an example. Let's assume that I want to extract the five (out of six) links on the top of Scrapy's Offcial Page:

[image]

And here is my spider. Any ideas?

```
class dmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["scrapy.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://scrapy.org/",
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\S+/'), restrict_xpaths=('/html/body/div[1]/div/ul')), callback='first_level'),
    )
    def first_level(self, response):
        taco = dmozItem()
        taco['basic_url'] = response.url
        return taco
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the `restrict_xpaths` parameter. See the [LxmlLinkExtractor documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor)

**Edit:**

You can also pass a list to `restrict_xpaths`.

**Edit 2:**

Full example that should work:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class dmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    basic_url = scrapy.Field()

class dmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["scrapy.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://scrapy.org/",
    ]

    def clean_url(value):
        return value.replace('/../', '/')

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=('\S+/'),
                restrict_xpaths=(['.//ul[@class="navigation"]/a[1]',
                                  './/ul[@class="navigation"]/a[2]',
                                  './/ul[@class="navigation"]/a[3]',
                                  './/ul[@class="navigation"]/a[4]',
                                  './/ul[@class="navigation"]/a[5]']),
                process_value=clean_url
            ),
            callback='first_level'),
    )

    def first_level(self, response):
        taco = dmozItem()
        taco['basic_url'] = response.url
        return taco
```

Comment: Added process_value to fix the links of your example.

Comment: ok. so, the Scrapy.org example works great! But I'm still facing problems with my web site of interest. It seems that the XPath there is wrong although I got it straight from Chrome's developer tool. Do you know a quick and accurate way to validate XPath within Scrapy?

Comment: `scrapy shell` can be used for that. See [http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#scrapy-shell] (documentation) for examples. (Looking on your xpaths, I would suggest to remove all the `tbody` tags - these are likely inserted by the browser!)